# Jenkins pipeline not able to execute the HttpClient.execute(HttpPost)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

My groovy config in Jenkins pipeline:

```
HttpUriRequest postRequestLogin = new HttpPost();

List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_username", "${user}"))
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_password", "${pass}"))
postRequestLogin.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters))

CloseableHttpResponse responseLogin = httpClient.execute(postRequestLogin)
```

I got the following error:

> No signature of method:
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.execute() is applicable
>   for argument types: (org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost) values:
>   [org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost@eb47360] Possible solutions:
>   execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest),
>   execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,
>   org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler),
>   execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost, org.apache.http.HttpRequest),
>   execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext),
>   execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost, org.apache.http.HttpRequest,
>   org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler),
>   execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,
>   org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler,
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way to make the request:

```
    URL url = url_string.toURL()
    // Create authorization header format using Base64 encoding
    String userpass = username + ":" + apiKey;
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());
    // Open connection
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection()

    connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuthString())
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST")
    connection.doOutput = false;

    // Open input stream
    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream()
    // Close the stream
    inputStream.close()

    return connection.getResponseCode()
```